# Looking for query to get meta_value

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So i'm using Wordpress, Woocommerce and the "Product Video for WooCommerce" plugin by *Addify*. The URL to a mp4 video is stored in the:

```
wp_postmeta table
```

In this table, the post_id matches the product.
In the "meta_value" i can see the URL i've added.

No my question;
I want to place a download button that downloads the video stored in this location.
I've located the woocommerce hook where the button needs to come, but I can't figure out how to fetch the url from this meta_value.

My code skills are very basic so this is to complicated for me.
Can anyone help me out on this?

This showed me that the URL is visible but surely not the end goal :-)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_share', 'custom_button', 20 );
function custom_button() {
$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '', true);
print_r($meta); 

}
  //Here I want to add the button
print '<button>Download video</button>';
```

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'woocommerce_share' hook is an action, not filter.

Try this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_share', 'custom_button', 20 );
function custom_button() {
    $download_url = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'afpv_cus_featured_video_id', true);

    if ( empty( $download_url ) ) { // do not print anything if download_url doesn't exists
        return;
    }

    // print the download button
    printf( '<a href="%s" class="button" target="_blank" download>%s</a>', 
        esc_url( $download_url ), 
        __( 'Download video', 'text-domain' ) // string can be translated, change text-domain by the theme domain or plugin domain
    );
}
```

Comment: Amazing Jo ! It is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot for getting a proper answer so fast! Many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, can you set my answer as correct answer please ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers